# NUnit Error: Not a test assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

I have a solution with 3 projects in it (one is a C# class-library for unit tests, another is a MVC 2 web application)

I have included all the necessary references for NUnit, and I have correctly decorated the classes and methods with `[TestFixture]` and `[Test]` respectively.

It compiles with no errors.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Pro

When I try to open UnitTests.dll in NUnit, I get the following error:

> Not a test assembly.
>   This assembly was not built with any known testing framework.

Comment: That is a stupid question that I'll ask but, have you opened the right assembly from the NUnit Testing GUI? If you have one project for testing, then it is the one you should open. Would you have accidently opened another different assembly?

Comment: Yes. I opened C:\websites\mvc\my_application\unittests\bin\debug\unittests.dll

Comment: I've tried both 2.5.8 & 2.5.9 of NUnit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may or may not be the issue that you are facing, but I had exactly the same issue and I found that the dll I was loading was an old file.

Rebuild the project and then actually go into the directory that the dll is in and check that it has a creation/modification time that is current.

It's very easy, for example, to create:

```
my_project/
my_project/domain/
my_project/unit-tests/ (removed but not deleted on the HD, not visible in studio)
my_project/domain/unit-tests/ (visible as MyProject.UnitTests)
```

If you then load the dll in my_project/unit-tests/ you may not be loading the dll you just built.

Try also file -> save as while editing a test class, and see what *actual directory* it is being saved into, and check that the dll you are loading is from the same path.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reference to the assembly in the GAC? Take a look in tools > test assemblies of the NUnit GUI runner as per this blog posting:

http://blog.solien.com/archive/2010/02/09/unable-to-load-unit-test-the-assembly-was-not.aspx

Comment: Not sure but here's the output of tools > test assemblies:

Comment: nunit.exe ( 3884 )
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.4952 ( Net 2.0 )

nunit-agent.exe ( 2076 )
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.1 ( Net 4.0 )

  test-domain-UnitTests.nunit
    ApplicationBase: C:\Websites\mvc\my_application\UnitTests\bin\Debug
    Configuration File: C:\Websites\mvc\my_application\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.config
    UnitTests
      Path: C:\Websites\mvc\my_application\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.DLL
      Image Runtime Version: 4.0.30319
    UnitTests
      Path: C:\Websites\mvc\my_application\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.DLL
      Image Runtime Version: 4.0.30319