# Test dll built for/with NUnit "is not a NUnit Test" (answer included)

Tags: exception, testing, nunit

There is [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372981/nunit-error-not-a-test-assembly) about getting this in the output window. Their answer involved the GAC and dll versions. My answer is specific to my circumstance even though it showed the same symptoms.

Output window - Tests

```
'E:\CodeRepository-Git\DFBAzure\AzureMgmtServiceDashboard\Wp7AzureMgmt.DashboardFeeds.Test\bin\Debug\Wp7AzureMgmt.DashboardFeeds.Test.dll' is not a NUnit Test
```

My issue is that the App.config had a malformed value to a well-known key. I had already corrected this in the MVC web.config but forgot to fix it in the test.dll.

When I tried to run the dll from the NUnit gui (the project did load), the gui threw an unhandled exception. The details were:

```
 See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The configSource attribute must be a relative physical path, so the '/' character is not allowed. (E:\CodeRepository-Git\DFBAzure\AzureMgmtServiceDashboard\Wp7AzureMgmt.DashboardFeeds.Test\bin\Debug\Wp7AzureMgmt.DashboardFeeds.Test.dll.config line 12)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.get_Section()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InitializeSockets()
   at System.Net.IPAddress.InternalParse(String ipString, Boolean tryParse)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink..ctor(String channelURI, TcpClientChannel channel)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSinkProvider.CreateSink(IChannelSender channel, String url, Object remoteChannelData)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider.CreateSink(IChannelSender channel, String url, Object remoteChannelData)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientChannel.CreateMessageSink(String url, Object remoteChannelData, String& objectURI)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.FindDelayLoadChannelForCreateMessageSink(String url, Object data, String& objectURI)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.CreateEnvoyAndChannelSinks(MarshalByRefObject tpOrObject, ObjRef objectRef, IMessageSink& chnlSink, IMessageSink& envoySink)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.InternalUnmarshal(ObjRef objectRef, Object proxy, Boolean fRefine)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef.GetRealObjectHelper()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.BeginRun(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter, Boolean captureTrace, LoggingThreshold logLevel)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.BeginRun(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter, Boolean captureTrace, LoggingThreshold logLevel)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.BeginRun(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter, Boolean tracing, LoggingThreshold logLevel)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.RunTests(ITestFilter filter)
   at NUnit.UiKit.TestSuiteTreeView.RunTests(ITest[] tests, Boolean ignoreCategories)
   at NUnit.Gui.NUnitForm.runButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
nunit
    Assembly Version: 2.6.0.12051
    Win32 Version: 2.6.0.12051
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6/bin/nunit.exe
----------------------------------------
nunit-gui-runner
    Assembly Version: 2.6.0.12051
    Win32 Version: 2.6.0.12051
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6/bin/lib/nunit-gui-runner.DLL
----------------------------------------
nunit.core
    Assembly Version: 2.6.0.12051
    Win32 Version: 2.6.0.12051
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6/bin/lib/nunit.core.DLL
----------------------------------------
nunit.util
    Assembly Version: 2.6.0.12051
    Win32 Version: 2.6.0.12051
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6/bin/lib/nunit.util.DLL
----------------------------------------
nunit.core.interfaces
    Assembly Version: 2.6.0.12051
    Win32 Version: 2.6.0.12051
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6/bin/lib/nunit.core.interfaces.DLL
----------------------------------------
nunit.uikit
    Assembly Version: 2.6.0.12051
    Win32 Version: 2.6.0.12051
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6/bin/lib/nunit.uikit.DLL
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5458 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
nunit.uiexception
    Assembly Version: 2.6.0.12051
    Win32 Version: 2.6.0.12051
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6/bin/lib/nunit.uiexception.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
vg5zflea
    Assembly Version: 2.6.0.12051
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Could you move the answer portion of your question to an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

The important bit is:

```
The configSource attribute must be a relative physical path, so the '/' character is not allowed.
```

Which, when I finally stopped looking at NUnit versions and the GAC, solved my problem with a simple fix.