# This assembly was not built with any known testing framework Error when i try to run Nuint test inside VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit

I have a c-sharp project inside my visual studio 2010 express , so i did the following to be able to run the Nunit test:-
1. i download the "NUnit-2.6.1.msi".
2, i add a reference to the "Nunit.framework.dll" from the C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.1\bin\framework
3. i add the folloiwng configuration from "External Tool"

- command:  C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.1\bin\nunit.exe
- Argument: /run $(ProjectDir)/$(ProjectFileName)
- Intial Directory: $(ProjectDir).

But when i try to run the Nunit test from Visual studio  the following error occured:-
**This assembly was not built with any known testing framework**

Can anyone help me in solving this problem ??
Best Regards

Comment: How are you running the test?  Are you executing the external tool or are you using the VS2010 built-in test options?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this problem once, I solved it by doing the following:

1. Adding an Using statement for NUnit (using NUnit.Framework;)
2. The class attribute should be [TestFixture] and NOT [TestClass]
3. Decorate your Test methods with the attribute [Test] and NOT [TestMethod]

Hope this helps

Comment: after using these still getting same error.please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are loading an old dll. Check that your dll is the one containing your latest changes.
See also [NUnit Error: Not a test assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372981/nunit-error-not-a-test-assembly)